# With NO written contract or non-compete in place, how does the law (NY, NJ, FL, CA) view contacting former clients?

Tags: breach-of-contract, non-compete

Is there any kind of generalized legal rule of thumb in reference to contacting former prospects/clients/colleagues once you've left/been terminated, etc.? With no written contract or non-compete in place is a former employee/independent contractor free to contact and interact with whomever they want? Also, what determines if the prospect or client is a "trade secret" in the eyes of the law? Thanks.

Comment: Could you elaborate or let me know what I'm missing with respect to the prospect/client him/her/itself being a trade secret?

Comment: I am simply referring to a client or person that was met while employed or working with the former employer. Would that make it something "owned" by the business, making it a "trade secret?"